# How to open a p:autoComplete suggestion list on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have an `AutoComplete` component which uses a dropdown button. I don't like that suggestions are only shown when I click the dropdown button (or start typing). I would like to show the suggestions on focus of the input component. So I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```html
<p:autoComplete widgetVar="myAutoComplete"
                dropdown="true"
                onfocus="PF('myAutoComplete').dropdown.trigger('mouseup')"
                ...>
```

In the component listener it triggers a focus on the input, so it's causing a loop:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/f693d1df18192c2bf2c6f715d55e3934ae255c06/primefaces/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/autocomplete/autocomplete.js#L374-L378

```js
this.dropdown.on("mouseup", function() {
    if ($this.active) {
        $this.searchWithDropdown();
        $this.input.trigger('focus');
    }
}
```

I couldn't find an other way to do it. Is there a way to do this without monkey patching the component?

I'm on PrimeFaces 12.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code to use `searchWithDropdown` to avoid the events

```xml
<p:autoComplete widgetVar="myAutoComplete"
                dropdown="true"
                onfocus="PF('myAutoComplete').searchWithDropdown()"
                ...>
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, but it will reopen the panel when the component looses focus. Could be something at my end. Will debug further.